# How to gracefully stop an Azure WebJob written for Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm aware that using the a `setting.job` file one can [gracefully shutdown an Azure WebJob](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VrQOf1grL4Y). This is my file:

```
    {
      "schedule": "0 */10 * * * *",
      "stopping_wait_time": 120
    }
```

I had written a WebJob in javascript. The WebJob runs on Nodejs. It is configured as on demand and triggered every 10 minutes by the `setting.job`. For some reason my `setting.job` file does not shutdown the WebJob gracefully. It always end failed.

Maybe I'm missing something or not understand completely how the shutdown of a WebJob ends but I ended with a nasty tweak in the `run.js`:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        process.exit();
    }, 30000);
```

The piece of code is executed at the end of the script. I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution beside the one that I'm using.

`run.js` example:

```
    const http = require('http');
    const request = require('request');
    const fb = require('firebase');

    request(process.env.SourceUrl, function (error, response, body) {
        'use strict';
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // Process data from body
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
    });

    // Nasty hack to end gracefully
    setTimeout(function () {
       process.exit();
    }, 6000);
```

Comment: When you run your job locally, does it close by itself or do you need to ctrl+c to escape?

Comment: Yes, most of the times I just close the cmd windows.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood. Do you press ctrl+c/close the window? If this is the case, then it's likely you have a listener/callback still in your WebJob. If you posted some code, I could help you find this. (but don't share anything you don't want people to see. :))

Comment: Sure, I'll going to update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the graceful way is waiting for the job done completely, not break off in processing.

```
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request');
const fb = require('firebase');

var sig = -1;

request(process.env.SourceUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    'use strict';
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Process data from body

            sig = 0;
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            sig = 1;
        }
});

setInterval(function() {
    if(sig > -1) {
        process.exit(sig);
    }
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Hi Peter, what is the difference of using  `setInterval` instead `setTimeout`?

Comment: @James Function `setTimeout` only runs the code/function once after the timeout. It might not be sure the request done completely if the timeout is too short. Or the process deferred exit, not immediately if the timeout is too long.

Comment: I selected this answer as the solution because practically it is quite similar to the solution implemented. Thanks a lot for the support!

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way achieve your goal is to call process.exit after you've finished your business logic. This gives you full control over the lifecycle of your WebJob.

```
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request');
const fb = require('firebase');

request(process.env.SourceUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    'use strict';
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Process data from body

            //When finished
            process.exit(0);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            process.exit(1); // provide a non-zero error, because the job failed
        }
});
```

Comment: Apparently kill the process so abruptly does not allow the whole business logic to complete successfully. Sees something is still running behind the scenes and the data does not arrive at final end point.

Comment: If you're doing something with the data, like adding it to a database, you need to kill the process when you've completed that - which is likely in a subsequent callback.